# terminal was slow(after finishing the process)after fixing it: unknown characters in terminal appears

Tags: command-line, bash, 17.10, gnome-terminal, .profile

My terminal was slow.

Every time after finishing the process like:

- Installing software or `sudo apt update` etc...

I should wait for the shell for about 5-10 sec to type next commands.

So i searched to fix this problem.
I found one:

Add: `set -x` in the first of the .profile and .bashrc and `set +x` in the last line of that file again(.profile and .bashrc), then run `bash --login` in terminal.

The problem fixed and everything works perfect...
But after rebooting now i see unknown characters in terminal every-time when i press `CTRL`+`ALT`+`T`:

[image]

So i should type `clear` to have normal terminal like before!
What are these!? And how can i clear them from the terminal without slow down from the terminals speed!?

My .bashrc:

```
# ~/.bashrc: executed by bash(1) for non-login shells.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files (in the package bash-doc)
# for examples

# If not running interactively, don't do anything
set -x
case $- in
    *i*) ;;
      *) return;;
esac

# don't put duplicate lines or lines starting with space in the history.
# See bash(1) for more options
HISTCONTROL=ignoreboth

# append to the history file, don't overwrite it
shopt -s histappend

# for setting history length see HISTSIZE and HISTFILESIZE in bash(1)
HISTSIZE=1000
HISTFILESIZE=2000

# check the window size after each command and, if necessary,
# update the values of LINES and COLUMNS.
shopt -s checkwinsize

# If set, the pattern "**" used in a pathname expansion context will
# match all files and zero or more directories and subdirectories.
#shopt -s globstar

# make less more friendly for non-text input files, see lesspipe(1)
[ -x /usr/bin/lesspipe ] && eval "$(SHELL=/bin/sh lesspipe)"

# set variable identifying the chroot you work in (used in the prompt below)
if [ -z "${debian_chroot:-}" ] && [ -r /etc/debian_chroot ]; then
    debian_chroot=$(cat /etc/debian_chroot)
fi

# set a fancy prompt (non-color, unless we know we "want" color)
case "$TERM" in
    xterm-color|*-256color) color_prompt=yes;;
esac

# uncomment for a colored prompt, if the terminal has the capability; turned
# off by default to not distract the user: the focus in a terminal window
# should be on the output of commands, not on the prompt
#force_color_prompt=yes

if [ -n "$force_color_prompt" ]; then
    if [ -x /usr/bin/tput ] && tput setaf 1 >&/dev/null; then
    # We have color support; assume it's compliant with Ecma-48
    # (ISO/IEC-6429). (Lack of such support is extremely rare, and such
    # a case would tend to support setf rather than setaf.)
    color_prompt=yes
    else
    color_prompt=
    fi
fi

if [ "$color_prompt" = yes ]; then
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\[\033[01;32m\]\u@\h\[\033[00m\]:\[\033[01;34m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$ '
else
    PS1='${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h:\w\$ '
fi
unset color_prompt force_color_prompt

# If this is an xterm set the title to user@host:dir
case "$TERM" in
xterm*|rxvt*)
    PS1="\[\e]0;${debian_chroot:+($debian_chroot)}\u@\h: \w\a\]$PS1"
    ;;
*)
    ;;
esac

# enable color support of ls and also add handy aliases
if [ -x /usr/bin/dircolors ]; then
    test -r ~/.dircolors && eval "$(dircolors -b ~/.dircolors)" || eval "$(dircolors -b)"
    alias ls='ls --color=auto'
    #alias dir='dir --color=auto'
    #alias vdir='vdir --color=auto'

    alias grep='grep --color=auto'
    alias fgrep='fgrep --color=auto'
    alias egrep='egrep --color=auto'
fi

# colored GCC warnings and errors
#export GCC_COLORS='error=01;31:warning=01;35:note=01;36:caret=01;32:locus=01:quote=01'

# some more ls aliases
alias ll='ls -alF'
alias la='ls -A'
alias l='ls -CF'

# Add an "alert" alias for long running commands.  Use like so:
#   sleep 10; alert
alias alert='notify-send --urgency=low -i "$([ $? = 0 ] && echo terminal || echo error)" "$(history|tail -n1|sed -e '\''s/^\s*[0-9]\+\s*//;s/[;&|]\s*alert$//'\'')"'

# Alias definitions.
# You may want to put all your additions into a separate file like
# ~/.bash_aliases, instead of adding them here directly.
# See /usr/share/doc/bash-doc/examples in the bash-doc package.

if [ -f ~/.bash_aliases ]; then
    . ~/.bash_aliases
fi

# enable programmable completion features (you don't need to enable
# this, if it's already enabled in /etc/bash.bashrc and /etc/profile
# sources /etc/bash.bashrc).
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi
set +x
```

My .profile:

```
# ~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists.
# see /usr/share/doc/bash/examples/startup-files for examples.
# the files are located in the bash-doc package.

# the default umask is set in /etc/profile; for setting the umask
# for ssh logins, install and configure the libpam-umask package.
#umask 022

# if running bash
set -x
if [ -n "$BASH_VERSION" ]; then
    # include .bashrc if it exists
    if [ -f "$HOME/.bashrc" ]; then
    . "$HOME/.bashrc"
    fi
fi

# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
set +x
```

Comment: @user68168 it's not mac os.... macbuntu theme installed on ubuntu 17.10

Comment: You need to type clear everytime you start a new terminal ?

Comment: @An0n i can use terminal well without typing it... but i just want that normal terminal appear without these characters...

Comment: You could try ' rm -i ~/.profile ~/.bash* ' and rm -f ~/Library/Preferences/com.apple.Terminal.plist '

Comment: And just setting `set -x` really helped with your original issue? It's hard to believe because AFAIC it just outputs stuff (as you noticed), aside from that it should change *nothing*. The behaviour you're describing is exactly the expected one after all… Could you please add the source of this tip?

Comment: @dessert idk but it was helpful ... let me clear them and test again! and i'll report you after 1 or 2 day

Comment: @dessert i removed them... maybe i have too many softwares in lptp and that's why my terminal is slower then before ,i should find another solutions thanks anyway

Comment: On a totally unrelated note: Terminal emulators are meant to be used with monospace fonts for much better readability.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is the effect of `set -x` as explained in `man bash`:

> -x      After  expanding  each simple command, for command, case
>                         command, select  command,  or  arithmetic  for  command,
>                         display  the  expanded  value  of  PS4,  followed by the
>                         command and its expanded arguments  or  associated  word
>                         list.

As the commands in your `~/.bashrc` are executed when you open a terminal and to this time apparently `set -x` is set, you get all its output in your fresh terminal. To disable it, just remove all the `set -x` and `set +x` line you introduced.

Comment: forgot to say: i've already added both of `set -x` and `set+x`  in .bashrc and .profile @dessert

Comment: @Sss so - **remove them** - they are only intended for diagnostic purposes